# Is it possible to have an augment/conditional type, that adds `undefined` ONLY to properties that currently are null? (Or vice versa)

Tags: typescript

I don't have expertise with conditional types so I'm not managing to make it work. But imagine that you have this type:

```
type MyType = {
  name: number;
  description: string | null;
  title: string | null;
}
```

And I want to augment it with something like

```
type OutputType = AugmentType<MyType>;
```

So that it appends another type, say, `undefined` ONLY to the keys of a type, say, `null`.

Appending `undefined` only to `null` keys would end up resulting in:

```
type OutputType = {
  name: number; // Kept intact
  description: string | null | undefined; // Undefined appended
  title: string | null | undefined;  // Undefined appended
}
```

Typescript version doesn't matter, I'm using the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, super easy. Only wrinkle is the direction of extends is a bit weird.

```
type NullOrUndefined<TModel> = { [Key in keyof TModel]: null extends TModel[Key] ? (TModel[Key] | undefined) : TModel[Key] };
type OutputType = NullOrUndefined<MyType>;
```

Basically make a new remapped type, and if the type of the value at a given key includes null, or in undefined as well.

Comment: Ohhhh I didn't realize we could do the condition in the key as well. I was trying to do it in the generics "<>" section.

It worked just fine. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! glad to help. If you don't mind, set the answer as a solution to help others find it in the future. Good luck Typescripting!

Comment: Yup, just did it. It wasn't allowing me to do it earlier because I had to wait for 3 more minutes. Thanks again!

Comment: Conventionally, type parameters are written as a single (or a few) uppercase characters; I would suggest you change `key` to something like `K`.

Comment: I used the key name specifically to make it more understandable. K does not tell a beginner much. And in remapped types it is perfectly acceptable to use a descriptive name. Although I agree it should have been upper cased. The official handbook uses Property, although I like Key better since it is really just the name. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html